# Problemas con python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Estoy trabajando con:
Python == 3.9.0
Django == 3.1.3
PostgreSQL == 13.1

Al momento de ejecutar `python manage.py migrate` me retorna lo siguiente al inicio:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con django.
Cualquier ayuda es útil,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer cuando se utiliza la librería `psycopg2`  aquí:

```
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

La última versión que soporta es la de Python 3.8 puedes verlo en [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/#description).

Normalmente cuando sale una nueva versión de Python como la 3.9 (salió en octubre 2020), salvo que quieras hacer algo con esa versión, lo mejor es esperarse durante un tiempo (6 meses), para dar tiempo a todo el ecosistema de librerías abiertas se actualice a dicha versión.

Incluso librerías con mucho soporte como `Tensorflow` (Google está detrás de ella). Todavía tienen problemas con Python 3.8 **que salió hace más de un año**.

Esto se debe a que al ser software abierto, no es una empresa con una organización que lanza una actualización, si no que son personas trabajando independientemente, que actualizan las librerías cuando pueden.